# View code coverage of nodejs from an E2E test

Tags: node.js, e2e-testing

I have a nodejs app which exposes a REST API. I have a test suite written in java (restassured) which I use to test this nodejs app. The test suite makes REST calls and verifies the results.

Is there any way I can generate a code coverage report for this test suite?